# Eclipse/Subversive: Startup Guide

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have installed SVN and configure eclipse with SVN using subversive plugin.

Now i am in search of tutorial which guide how to create new java projects which stored both on local drive and remote SVN repository.

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go: [creating svn repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html)

by the way,do you own or have the access rights to a particular svn server ?

Comment: Yes i have access to SVN server and i have created repository also. Now i want to guide developers how they can create new java projects on eclipse making sure that everything get copy/synchronize in SVN repo. So i am looking for guide for developers.

Comment: i have tried one option Project Structure which comes after configuring repository. But it create a project with trunk,tags,branches on remote repository. i want it also get saved on local drive.

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan i hope [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/) will help.